# Probability of getting of an elevator

Tags: probability

Lets say there is 10 people getting into an elevator. Each person gets off at a randomly selected floor between *1* and *10*. Assume that each person's destination is independent of everyone else's destination. Then what is the probability that the floor stops at floor 3?

Comment: I added some more details in it sorry for being unclear.

Comment: **Much** better!

Answer (score 2):

We will need to assume **independence**. And that "randomly chosen" should be interpreted to mean that all floors are equally likely. (There are many othr interpretations.)

What is the probability that person $i$ does not get off at Floor $3$? What is the probability none of the $10$ get off at Floor $3$?